# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}| < \infty \implies \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_{n}| < \infty$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, number-theory

Suppose that $\{a_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N}, \{b_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb N} \subset \mathbb C$
such that both the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ and $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n}$ converges, and its sum are equal, that is, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}b_{n}.$

We assume that, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n}$ converges absolutely, that is, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |a_{n}| < \infty.$

> **My Question**: Can we expect,  the series, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} b_{n} $ converges absolutely, that is, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} |b_{n}| < \infty$; Or we get a counter example ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.
Take $b_n=(-1)^nn^{-1}$, $a_1=\sum b_n$, $a_k=0$ for $k>1$.

Comment: The tight writing misled me at first. +1

Answer (score 4):

The answer is No:

Let $\sum_na_n$ an absolutely convergent series and denote $S$ its sum and let $\sum_n c_n$ a conditionally convergent series and denote $S'$ its sum then we define the series $\sum_n b_n$ by
$$b_1=c_1-S'+S\quad;\quad b_n=c_n\;\forall n\ge 2$$
hence 
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n$$
but $\sum_{n=1}^\infty|b_n|=\infty$.

Answer (score 3):

Of course not, just set
$$
a_n=\frac{\ln 2}{2^n}\qquad b_n=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}
$$
then
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n=\sum_{n=1}^\infty |a_n|=\ln 2=\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n
$$
but
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |b_n|=+\infty
$$

Comment: Great counter example. +1